# What's the difference between the "global queue" and the "main queue" in GCD?

Tags: iphone, ios, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

Among some other ways, there are these two ways to get queues in `GCD`:

```
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_get_main_queue();
```

If I'm not completely wrong, the "main queue" is executing on the main thread and is good for "callback" blocks which execute UI work.

Does this mean a "global queue" is one that runs on a background thread?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The main queue does indeed run on the main thread like you say.

The global queues are concurrent queues and from the main page for dispatch_get_global_queue:

> Unlike the main queue or queues allocated with
>   dispatch_queue_create(), the global concurrent queues
>   schedule blocks as soon as threads become available ("non-FIFO" completion order). The global concurrent
>        queues represent three priority bands:
>
> ```
>        •   DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
>        •   DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
>        •   DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW
> ```
>
> Blocks submitted to the high priority global queue will be invoked before those submitted to the
>   default or low priority global queues. Blocks submitted to the low priority global queue will only be
>   invoked if no blocks are pending on the default or high priority queues.

So, they are queues which run on background threads as and when they become available. They're "non-FIFO" so ordering is not guaranteed.

Comment: Is it correct to say that global queues are concurrent queues and you cannot create your own concurrent queues (with `dispatch_queue_create` or something else)?

Comment: reference for the "non-FIFO" please?

Answer (score 33):

The 5 queues (4 background, 1 main) all have different thread priorities ([`-[NSThread threadPriority]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSThread/threadPriority)) too:

```
                            -main- : 0.758065
      DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH : 0.532258
   DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT : 0.500000
       DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW : 0.467742
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND : 0.000000
```

(tested on an iPod 4th gen and the simulator on a MacBook Pro)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You can run code like this on a device to test it:

```
dispatch_async(
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSLog(@"Block 1a");
            NSAssert(![NSThread isMainThread], @"Wrong thread!");
            NSLog(@"Block 1b");
        });
dispatch_async(
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"Block 2a");
                    NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"Wrong thread!");
                    NSLog(@"Block 2b");
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

Global dispatch queue :

1. Tasks in concurrent queue executes concurrently  [background threads]
2. Tasks are still started in the order that they were added to the queue

Main dispatch queue :

1. Available serial queue that executes tasks on the application's main
   thread.
2. It is usually called from a background queue when some
   background processing has finished and the user interface needs to
   be updated.